# Use unresolved identifier when declaring variable in if-statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift

Why in `then` clause `name` is resolved as variable, but in `else` clause I get error :

`Use unresolved identifier 'name'`

The code:

```
    var optionalName: String? = "Peter"
    var greeting = "Hello!"
    if let name = optionalName {
        greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
    }
    else {
        greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's how optional binding works.

`name` gets initialized and assigned only if `optionalName` is not empty.

In case `optionalName` is `nil`, you get into the `else` branch and you already know that `optionalName` is empty.

From the official book:

> If the optional value is `nil`, the conditional is false and the code in braces is skipped. Otherwise, the optional value is unwrapped and assigned to the constant after `let`, which makes the unwrapped value available inside the block of code.

Comment: So if `optionalName` is empty then `name` variable will be even not create with nil value?

Comment: @Ossir exactly. I added a quote from the official book, you can read it above.

Answer (score 0):

Name is only defined as a constant if optional name is not nil. If optional name is nil, why would you want name to be assigned to that value?